# show this number is not a prime number

Tags: prime-numbers

The following problem is a special case [Show this number always is composite number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2771998/show-this-number-always-is-composite-number?noredirect=1&lq=1) , but I think this special case is relatively difficult to deal with, that is, if this is solved, it may solve the general situation.

> show this number
>   $$A=2004^{2005}+1002^{2005}\cdot 2005^{1002}+2005^{2004}$$is not a prime number.

This is  a question from an eighth-grade math contest exercise, (this .：see:[at last page problem 20](http://www.docin.com/p-1470836157.html)
I'm thinking mod 3, mod 5, mod 7. It doesn't seem to work.
because
$$A\equiv 0+0+1=1\pmod 3$$
$$A\equiv -1+0+0=4\pmod 5$$
Use Fermat's little theorem
$$A\equiv 2+1+3^{0}=4\pmod 7$$

Comment: As an extension, it might also be interesting to find for which $x$ makes $$(2x)^{2x+1}+x^{2x+1}\cdot (2x+1)^x + (2x+1)^{2x}$$ prime...

Comment: @TheSimpliFire That is this question exactly: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2771998/show-this-number-always-is-composite-number

Comment: @Sil Thanks! I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 7):

Actually the smallest prime factor of A turns out to be $670543$. This limits the number of approaches that could possibly work: don't bother checking mod small primes.

Comment: Let $x=1002^{2005},\ y=2005^{1002}, then\\ A=x^2+xy+y^2$

Comment: @herbsteinberg No, look again.  But even if it were true, it wouldn't help.

Comment: @herbsteinberg $x^2 \neq 2004^{2005}$.

Comment: You are right - it should be$2^{2005}x+xy+y^2$

Comment: Explain, please, (my English is quite poor) what you mean by "smallest prime factor of A turns out to be 670543". Does it mean that this number is in effect a factor of A? In this case you have shown that A is not a prime and then you would deserve the recognition of the best answer.

Comment: Yes, $670543$ is a factor of A.  Here's confirmation from [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2004%5E2005%2B1002%5E2005*2005%5E1002%2B2005%5E2004+mod+670543)

Comment: So your answer is not "partial" but "total". Very good. Can you tell me how do you find this prime? Trial and errors with biblical patience? Regards.

Comment: In Maple: ifactor(A, easy).

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately for me, I do not know these techniques with powerful calculators.

Comment: You don't need anything powerful, the factor is not that large.  In Python, "A=2004\*\*2005 + 1002\*\*2005 \* 2005\*\*1002 + 2005\*\*2004" followed by "i=2" and "while A % i: i += 1".

Comment: @mjqxxxx: Very fine your reply. What happens is that I am somewhat allergic to these calculations. Thank you very much anyway.

Answer (score 1):

$$2004^{2005}+1002^{2005} 2005^{1002}+2005^{2004}$$
$$x=2004$$
$$x^{x+1}+\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{x+1} (x+1)^{x/2}+(x+1)^x=2^{-x-1} \left(x^{x+1} (x+1)^{x/2}+2^{x+1} x^{x+1}+2^{x+1} (x+1)^x\right)$$

which should never be prime when $x$ is even:

Consider the portion (ignoring the extra $2^{x+1}$ for now):

$$\left(x^{x+1}+(x+1)^{x}\right)$$

Then, let $x={1,2,3,...}$, but don't evaluate to see:

$$x^2+x+1$$
$$x^3+x^2+2 x+1$$
$$x^4+x^3+3 x^2+3 x+1$$
...

Then the other portion:

$$\left(x^{x+1}(x+1)^{x/2}\right)$$

$$x^4+x^3$$
$$x^7+2 x^6+x^5$$
$$x^{10}+3x^9+3x^8+x^7$$
...

So the inside part of the polynomial is the sum of **two** different variations of binomial expansions with different powers for $x$, so it cannot be prime when $x$ is even.

One other note: it's almost like $2^2(x^2+x+1)+x^4+x^3$ characterizes the entire function.

I'm pretty sleepy right now, if I missed something let me know. (nicely, please)